# show each product price in the checkout summary

Tags: checkout, price, products

In the checkout summary, the products * quantity price is showing. With this, I want to show the price of one item. It means with the total price I also want to show the one each product's price in the checkout summary.

This is checkout summary
Total Price of the total quantity is coming but I want to show also one unit price, You can show right after the product name or where you can add in the below screenshot.

Please don't disturb anything that is working now.

[image]

This is my Js which is running when I applied debugger on the JS

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details',
    'mage/translate',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Rokanthemes_OnePageCheckout/js/action/update-item',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, Component, $t, ko, _, customerData, updateItemAction, quote) {
    'use strict';
    var quoteItemData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Rokanthemes_OnePageCheckout/summary/item/details'
        },

        titleQtyBox: ko.observable($t('Qty')),
        number: null,
        getQtyBox: function(quoteItem) {
            var item = this.getItem(quoteItem.item_id);
            return item.qty_box;
        },
        getItem: function(item_id) {
            var itemElement = null;
            _.each(quoteItemData, function(element, index) {
                if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                    itemElement = element;
                }
            });
            return itemElement;
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} item
         * @returns void
         */
        updateQty: function (item) {
            if (item.qty < 0) {
                $(".error-message[itemId = '" + item.item_id + "']").text($t('Please enter the number greater than or equal to 0!'));
                return;
            }
            if (parseFloat(item.qty) != item.qty) {
                $(".error-message[itemId = '" + item.item_id + "']").text($t('Please enter number!'));
                return;
            }
            $(".error-message[itemId = '" + item.item_id + "']").text($t(''));
            updateItemAction(item).done(
                function (response) {
                    var totals = response.totals,
                        data = JSON.parse(this.data),
                        itemId = data.itemId,
                        itemsOrigin = [],
                        quoteItemData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
                    if (!response.status) {
                        var originItem = _.find(quoteItemData, function (index) {
                            return index.item_id == itemId;
                        });
                        $.each(totals.items, function (index) {
                            if (this.item_id == originItem.item_id) {
                                this.qty = originItem.qty;
                            }
                            itemsOrigin[index] = this;
                        });
                        totals.items = itemsOrigin;
                    } else {
                        customerData.reload('cart');
                    }
                    quote.setTotals(totals);
                }
            );
        },

        /**
         * @param data
         * @param event
         */
        updateQtyButton: function (data, event) {
            var element = event.target,
                action = element.getAttribute('action'),
                itemId = element.getAttribute('itemId'),
                qtyBox = element.getAttribute('qtyBox'),
                qtyInput = $('[itemId = ' + itemId + ']').parent().parent().find('input');
            if (typeof action === "undefined" || typeof itemId === "undefined" || typeof qtyInput === "undefined") {
                return;
            }
            var currentQty = parseFloat(qtyInput.val());
            var qtyBoxing = parseFloat(qtyBox);
            currentQty = Math.round(currentQty * 100);
            qtyBoxing = Math.round(qtyBoxing * 100);
            if (this.number != null && currentQty >= 100) {
                clearTimeout(this.number);
            }

            if (action == 'increase') {
                var nextQty = (currentQty + qtyBoxing)/100;
                nextQty = +nextQty.toFixed(2);
                //nextQty = +nextQty.toFixed(2);
                qtyInput.val(nextQty);
                this.number = setTimeout(function () {
                    qtyInput.trigger('change');
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                if (currentQty >= 100) {
                    var nextQty = (currentQty - qtyBoxing)/100;
                    nextQty = +nextQty.toFixed(2);
                    qtyInput.val(nextQty);
                    this.number = setTimeout(function () {
                        qtyInput.trigger('change');
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} itemId
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getProductUrl: function (itemId) {
            if (_.isUndefined(customerData.get('cart')())) {
                customerData.reload('cart');
            }
            var productUrl = 'javascript:void(0)',
                cartData = customerData.get('cart')(),
                items = cartData.items;

            var item = _.find(items, function (item) {
                return item.item_id == itemId;
            });

            if (!_.isUndefined(item) && item.product_has_url) {
                productUrl = item.product_url;
            }
            return productUrl;
        }
    });
});
```